# How to delay the start of a function

Tags: swift

so i have built my first application in X Code using swift, and i have also taken the time to add the game centre functionality to it, however my question is, how would i delay the start of my game, in order for game centre to load, as of right now, the game starts, and then the game centre banner appears on top of my game before disappearing.

would it be sufficient to use something like, on the function containing my main game attributes:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
```

or

would i be better off adding a splash screen?

if anyone has any other suggestions, that would be helpful.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to subscribe under GameCenter, listen a complete event and then produce your next initialization. Avoid timers in similar situations, because time of processing depends from many factors, and rely to specific delay is not good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are waiting for the game to load, then starting a timer is probably not the best solution, because you don't know how long the loading takes on different devices with different capabilities.

A better idea is to load your game and then have a completion method that is called to start the game when it is ready to be run.